# How to customize global message HTML?

Tags: magento-1, messages, global-messages

How do I customize the HTML for the global messages block?  it's called in most templates:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

But I can't find reference to what is generating the HTML anywhere - enabling template paths does not show if it is using a template or not.

Comment: Which message specifically are you looking to customize?

Answer (score 3):

The block responsible for generating messages as well as HTML format is under `core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php` which extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class.

All functions are within that class as well as HTML tags that are used to generate messages.

Comment: I wound up copying that file to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block & modifying the html output.   Work fine enough for my purposes.  but question, can I strip out all the other functions from my updated file or will Magento not 'inherit' them?

Comment: Yes, you can strip out all other functions but make your class extends Messages block then you end up overriding only one function and the rest functions will work as intended.

Comment: Also, if this answer helps please accept it. Thank you.